# Leaflet.js+d3.js circles with transition

Tags: d3.js, transition

I am trying to plot circles in Leaflet.js (a webmapping app), following  http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/ seems not to be dificult, but I'm having strange problems :.(  that you can see here: http://bl.ocks.org/3047025

In fact here you can see simple circles  and works fine if zooming (double click on map) and so on. But I want these features to be circles instead of paths. I think it is not possible (?)

I would like to have circles so I can apply transitions (from radius 0 to X, change color, gravities), events and so on.

Are these transitions in Circles+Leaflet.js possible?? as far as I tested, with paths it is not.

thanks in advance,

Pere

Answer (score 2):

Ziggy Johnson kindly answered my question in the d3.js googlegroup.

You can take a look how it's correctly done in http://bl.ocks.org/3087431

thanks again, Ziggy!